# ListenUsingL2CapOn permission denied

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am encountering an IO Exception (permission denied) error using ListenUsingL2cap. (I tried with an android 4.0.4 and 4.1.1 phone). I get the same 'permission denied' error even though I have BLUETOOTH_ADMIN in my manifest. I can create a socket just fine but I need to be able to listen on that psm for incoming connection requests, NOT listen on a socket that I connected myself.

My code:

```
int my_chan = 0x19;
Class<?>[] args = new Class[] { int.class };
Method listenOn = BluetoothAdapter.class.getDeclaredMethod("listenUsingL2capOn", args);
BluetoothServerSocket my_server = (BluetoothServerSocket)
(listenOn.invoke(mBluetoothAdapter, new Object[] { my_chan })); <--exception thrown here
m_oBluetoothSocket = my_server.accept();
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you find any new info on this?